# is there something wrong with my if statement?

Tags: javascript

I am checking the number of wrong lines with a for loop

```
var lines = dateinput.value.split(/\r?\n/);
var wrongLines ="";
for(var i = 0; i<lines.length ; i++){
    if (lines[i].match(regex) == null) {
        wrongLines += i + 1 +",";
    }
```

and I want to add different alerts for the number of the wrong lines

```
if (i = 1 ) {
alert('The date on line ' + wrongLines + ' is invalid. Please enter a valid date formatted DD/MM/YYYY');
}
else if (i > 1 ) {
alert('Dates on line ' + wrongLines + ' are invalid. Please enter a valid date formatted DD/MM/YYYY');
}
```

but it does not works - every time I get the first alert

Comment: = is assignment, i = 1 assigns 1 to i and will always evaluate as "truthy" ... check for equality i == 1 instead

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
if (i == 1 )
```

You are assigning values instead of comparing.

**N.B.** :

```
= means assigning 

== means comparing

=== means strict comparing
```

Answer (score 0):

at first impression, you should replace `if (i = 1)` with `if (i == 1)`